# Memory leak | LeakSanitizer: detected memory leaks | C programming

Tags: c, memory-leaks, malloc

I can't understand why the memory leak below happens, and how I can avoid it.

I am using malloc to allocate memory, and I initiate this memory allocated with a loop, copying value by value from string `a` to string `b`.

As far as my understanding goes, I am not leaving any memory whithout use.

my code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

void    run_test_one(void)
{
    char    *a;
    char    *b;
    int     i;

    a = "up the irons";
    b = (char *)malloc(13 * sizeof(char));
    i = 0;
    while(a[i] != '\0')
    {
        b[i] = a[i];
        ++i;
    }
    b[i] = '\0';
}

int main(void)
{
    run_test_one();

    return (0);
}
```

Error:

```
==9003==ERROR: LeakSanitizer: detected memory leaks

Direct leak of 13 byte(s) in 1 object(s) allocated from:
    #0 0x7ffb28c1db40 in __interceptor_malloc (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasan.so.4+0xdeb40)
    #1 0x55a9533b29c6 in run_test_one test.c:10
    #2 0x55a9533b2b04 in main test.c:22
    #3 0x7ffb2876fbf6 in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x21bf6)

SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: 13 byte(s) leaked in 1 allocation(s).
```

Comment: A "leak" is when you create or allocate a resource, but not destroy or free it. Like when you call `malloc` but never `free`. That's a leak.

Comment: Also, in C you [don't have to (and really shouldn't) cast the result of `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: IOW: add `free(b);` right before the line `b[i] = '\0';`

Comment: @Jabberwocky *After* I think you mean... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Memory is allocated by malloc regardless of using it or not. To fix leak you need to free memory.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

void    run_test_one(void)
{
    char    *a;
    char    *b;
    int     i;

    a = "up the irons";
    b = (char *)malloc(13 * sizeof(char));
    i = 0;
    while(a[i] != '\0')
    {
        b[i] = a[i];
        ++i;
    }
    b[i] = '\0';
    // new code
    free(b)
    // 
}

int main(void)
{
    run_test_one();

    return (0);
}
```

Second solution is to use automatic allocation. After your program leaves run_test_one function memory is freed:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

void    run_test_one(void)
{
    char    *a;
    char    *b;
    int     i;

    a = "up the irons";
    //edit
    char b[13];
    //
    i = 0;
    while(a[i] != '\0')
    {
        b[i] = a[i];
        ++i;
    }
    b[i] = '\0';
}

int main(void)
{
    run_test_one();

    return (0);
}
```